# Are Condition Codes / Flags stored in the processor registers or the main memory?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

I'm new to this, so I want to make sure that my comprehension of what I read is correct.

Also, registers are always processor registers, and there no other registers which are not a part of the processor (like registers in primary/secondary memory), correct?

Answer (score 4):

Most architectures have a dedicated register for storing flags. Modern x86, for example, [has one 32bit-register that stores all flags.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) Storing the flags in main memory would make accessing them incredibly slow, compared to a register. Some architectures do support moving the flags to either another register or directly onto the stack, and vice versa.

When talking about registers, most people are referring to registers in a processor. That's not to say there aren't any registers in your PC besides the ones in your CPU. GPUs, for example, also have registers. Your memory could have a register to temporarily store read/write addresses or keep track of other information, but when looking at processors you usually won't need to know about those.